# Moved to Tensorflow 2.0, training now hangs after third step

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Recently I have decided to move from version 1.14 of Tensorflow (gpu variant) to current version 2.0.

My current setup is:

- Tensorflow (gpu variant) 2.0
- Cudnn 7.6.4
- CUDA 10
- Python 3.6
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019

I did expect there will be some pain involved, but this caught me off guard.

When I tried to run one of my (now adjusted) 1.14 projects, the model built with now issue, and the training process begun smoothly. Only to completely stop after third step. 
The same project runs just fine on cpu variant of Tensorflow 2.0, but it takes several orders of magnitude longer to train all models.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Change hyperparameters
- Reinstall CUDA
- Reinstall tensorflow
- Reinstall cudnn
- disable validation
- check path variable

None of these did anything to help the issue. My only lead is the warning message:

```
 Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
```

Which I've never got with Tf 1.14 and am somewhat confused by.
I know CUDA works because I compiled and run several of the Nvidia examples. So the only real options left are related to Tensorflow or how it handles gpus.

But I have no idea how to move forward.

The log of the session follows:

```
019-11-27 01:03:57.910895: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4117: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  errors=errors,
2019-11-27 01:04:02.247959: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2019-11-27 01:04:02.277414: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.835
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0
2019-11-27 01:04:02.282378: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-27 01:04:02.286653: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-27 01:04:02.289629: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-11-27 01:04:02.295084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.835
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0
2019-11-27 01:04:02.299843: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-27 01:04:02.303965: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-27 01:04:03.043700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-27 01:04:03.047132: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0
2019-11-27 01:04:03.049453: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N
2019-11-27 01:04:03.052642: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6382 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 154, 64)           896000
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 150, 64)           20544
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 9600)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 300)               2880300
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 150)               45150
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 70)                10570
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                710
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 22
=================================================================
Total params: 3,853,296
Trainable params: 3,853,296
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train for 10 steps, validate for 50 steps
Epoch 1/40
2019-11-27 01:04:06.199581: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2019-11-27 01:04:06.430358: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2019-11-27 01:04:07.180709: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2019-11-27 01:04:07.425377: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:184] Profiler session started.
2019-11-27 01:04:07.431736: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_100.dll
 1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 32s - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.4375 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4375 - precision: 0.4375 - recall: 0.43752019-11-27 01:04:07.655586: I tensorflow/core/platform/default/device_tracer.cc:588] Collecting 148 kernel records, 21 memcpy records.
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W1127 01:04:07.730274  5696 callbacks.py:244] Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (0.138531). Check your callbacks.
 3/10 [========>.....................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.6167 - accuracy: 0.7000 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7000 - precision: 0.7000 - recall: 0.7000
```

Comment: It seems the big support is on Linux. No solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've been affected by the same issue. Turned out in my case the problem was the driver.

I first tried tensorflow-gpu with CUDA 10 and latest NVIDIA driver and stuck randomly at the training step, only to see the ptxas things you are showing.

Next I changed tensorflow version from 2.0 to 1.15 or 1.14, tweaking with Python version to see nothing helped.

After I uninstall the driver and install an old driver (432.00), the problem went away, though I continue to see the ptxas warning.